# How can I write lazy evaluating switch statements?

Tags: ruby

For a long time I tried desperately to get this to work, I've googled, I've tinkered, and I've asked some local Rubyists (though not pdx.rb, though I really should).

We were trying to do something like this at work:

```
case user.roles.included? (... magic ...) 
when ['admin', 'editor'] 
  then ...
when ['anonymous'] 
  then ...
end
```

So you can see how it feels like a `case`, but because it's not using `===` as El noted, it doesn't work. I know I can use `if` but it feels like a place where a `case` should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`when` uses the `===` operator to compare the value given to `case` against the argument given to `when`. Also `then` is unnecessary when appearing on a different line from the `when` statement The correct code for what you're trying to do is:

```
case x
when 16
  puts 'hi'
when Object
  puts 'obj'
end
```

As for the new addition to the question:

```
case user.roles.included? (... magic ...) 
when ['admin', 'editor'] 
  ... 
when ['anonymous'] 
  ... 
end
```

This doesn't work because Array's `===` doesn't map to `include`. I'm not sure where Array's `===` operator comes from or even what it does, but you could override it to provide the functionality you want.

Judging by the above code you want the `case` to trigger if one of the users roles matches the array. This will override `Array#===` to do just that:

```
class Array
  def === other_array
    ! (other_array & self).empty?
  end
end

case user.roles
when ['admin', 'editor'] 
  ... 
when ['anonymous'] 
  ... 
end
```

**Caveat:** Depending on where you override `Array#===` this can have unforeseen consequences, as it will change all arrays in that scope.  Given that `===` is being inherited from Object where it is an alias for `==`, I'm not expecting it to be a big problem.

Places where the new `===` differs from the old `===`:

- New `===` will return true if either array is a subset or reordering of the other.
- Old `===` will only return true if the two arrays are identical (order and contents).

So far as I know, `case`/`when` is the only time `===` could be implicitly called on an array.

Comment: If you want something more complicated than this, you should use `if` statements.

Comment: revised original question to be more clear. I think I explained poorly.

Comment: That Caveat is what was worrisome to me. Maybe I just have to accept that this isn't really something ruby can do? I guess when I think about how this is done in Haskell it's just different because it's basically a glorified if rather than a switch in the way we think of it. 

But that is cool to know that by overriding === on Array the switch could work the way I wanted!

Comment: Overriding === is really harmful and you shouldn't do this for such this case.

Comment: I honestly wouldn't worry too much about it. I just couldn't post the code without the caveat in good conscious. I've updated my answer to explain why it should not be too much of a problem.

Comment: I think this is probably the best solution I'll find to the problem. Maybe with my new knowledge I can post another question later or post to the pdx.rb mailing list and go over it some more. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 3):

```
case 
  when x == 16
    puts 'hi'
  when x.is_a?(Object)
    puts 'obj'
end
```

If I really understood the question, you just need to remove the `x` variable after the `case` keyword.

The lambda code didn't work because the lambda simply returns the argument.

```
names_l.call(names)
# => {:name => 'Terry'}
```

It's like running the following code:

```
case {:name => 'Terry'}
  when 'Terry'
    puts "Success!"
end
```

And `{:name => 'Terry'}` is not equal to `'Terry'`.

Comment: Hah, well that's half of my question. I had no idea it would be so easy. I'll try to clarify the rest of my issue. Maybe I can find the old code that was causing me problems.

Comment: Can't find the code, I'm on the wrong machine. But I'll give the situation. 

We were creating a named scope in rails that needed to act differently based on the roles of the user logged in. So the case needed to take a function and the when needed to be an array. 

Essentially I was thinking like this (pseudo-code):

case user.roles.included? (... magic ...)
when ['admin', 'editor']
when ['anonymous']
end

We ended up using a function but this has still bugged me. How can I get the when part to evaluate in the case? Or is this just faulty logic and has to be done with a function?

Comment: okay, no code here in comments. Hopefully you get what I'm getting at.

Comment: Your explanation about lambda is correct, but your case code is throwing missing then errors for me.

Comment: I tested the statement in irb against Ruby 1.8.6, 1.8.7 and 1.9.1 without getting any error message. :| Then keyword is not required with a line break.

Comment: Looks like irb was complaining about `x.is_a? Object`. x.is_a?(Object) works though.